# Play 2.1 computer-database sample - JPA for Java but not for Scala

Tags: scala, jpa, playframework, playframework-2.1

Is it odd that the computer-database sample in Play 2.x is written with JPA for the Java version but not for the Scala version?  Should one read something into that?

I am working on getting a Scala Play 2.1/JPA/MySQL PoC up and I just found this curious.

EDIT

It seems Play may indeed be moving away from JPA: [Playframework 2.1 doesn't find javax.persistence and play.db](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14731746/playframework-2-1-doesnt-find-javax-persistence-and-play-db)

Also, I am unable to get a simple entity fetch to work.  I can connect to my MySQL DB, but, when I have an Action method annotated with play.db.jpa.Transactional, I get a runtime error:

```
play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[RuntimeException: No EntityManager bound to this thread. Try to annotate your action method with @play.db.jpa.Transactional]
```

It doesn't recognize the TX.

Comment: The first issue was that jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
 is required in the conf file.  Check.  However, @Transaction on the Action method was still not recognized.  It is necessary to wrap the code in JPA.withTransaction to get it to work.

Comment: Anyone know why @Transactional does not work?  JPA.withTransaction() works fine but play.db.jpa.Transactional is supposed to do the same thing.  No effect when placed on a Controller Action method.

Comment: I found the same issue as you did. I suggest you create a service layer and use JPA.withTransaction in there, in order to wrap calls to your functions. I haven't done this yet, but this is the next step I need to do since my test cases employing JPA.withTransaction work fine whilst my Scala controllers fail when I use @Transactional.